# $d/dx$ is not continuous in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

To show that 
$\frac{d}{dx}:A \to L^2 (a,b)  $
is not continuous, where
$$A=\left\{u \in L^2 (a,b): \frac{du}{dx} \in  L^2 (a,b)
\right\} $$

I'm trying take a map's sussection that $|du_n|>c_n|u_n|$ but I cant find.

Comment: How about $u_n = \sin nx$?

Comment: What do you mean by "a map's sussection"? "Sussection" is not a English word